# How do I wait for multiple requests to the same URL in Cypress?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress, next.js13

I am working on a Cypress test where multiple requests are sent to the same URL but with different body content. Specifically, the test changes the input values in the UI, which triggers a new request to the server. The problem arises when attempting to validate the request body of each individual request using cy.wait() in combination with cy.intercept().

The structure of the test code is roughly as follows:

```
cy.intercept("POST", "/url").as("getCall");

cy.wait("@getCall").should((interception) => {
  // validation the body for the first request
});

// UI interactions that trigger a new request`

cy.wait("@getCall").should((interception) => {
  // validation for the body with new value for second request
});
```

The issue is that the second cy.wait() still gets the body from the first request, leading to failed assertions.

A workaround I've found is to give a different alias for the intercept on each request.:

```
cy.intercept("POST", "/url").as("getFirstCall");

cy.wait("@getFirstCall").should((interception) => {
  // validation for the first request
});

// UI interactions that trigger a new request

cy.intercept("POST", "/url").as("getSecondCall");
cy.wait("@getSecondCall").should((interception) => {
  // validation for the second request
});
```

This works but is a bit clumsy. Is there a better way to handle multiple requests to the same URL using cy.intercept() and cy.wait()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO there's nothing really wrong with your workaround, but you could simplify it by numbering the aliases.

This way you should be guaranteed the first call occurs for the first wait, etc.

```js
const interceptCall = 1
cy.intercept("POST", "/url", (req) => {
  req.alias = 'call' + interceptCall++   // use the current number and increment
  req.continue()                         // after setting the alias, continue
})

cy.wait("@call1").should((interception) => {
  // validation for the first request
})

// UI interactions that trigger a new request

cy.wait("@call2").should((interception) => {
  // validation for the first request
})
```

I am surprised that you are getting this problem - the initial code looks like it should work properly. Is there any further detail you can give, since I'm wondering it there's another issue at play here?

Comment: When my webpage loads, it sends a POST request to get products with min and max price values. I change these values in the UI and click a button, which sends a new request with the new values. In my tests, I use cy.intercept() to catch the requests and cy.wait() to validate the request body. But, the request body still shows the old values, not the new ones. This issue wasn't there before. After I added a new filter and did some efactoring, I need a new cy.intercept() before each new request.

Comment: The UI updates correctly with the expected changes and outside of the testing environment, also the requests and responses work with the updated values. The issue only arises in my tests when I use one cy.intercept() at the start of my test and then use cy.wait() for each request hitting the same endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, that helps give a clear picture. I was assuming it's the **response** you want to validate, but it's the **request** parameters! The only additional thing I can think of is your `cy.visit()` should be *after* the `cy.intercept()` since that fires the initial request, but if that were the problem, you would see an error that one of the `cy.wait()` was not fulfilled.

Comment: In any case, IMO your work-around is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can [alias individual requests](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Aliasing-individual-requests), which will allow you to write one singular intercept, and give the different requests different aliases.

```js
/**
 * Assuming the first call has a body of { foo: 'first' }
 * And the second call has a body of     { foo: 'second' }
 */

cy.intercept('POST', '/url', (req) => {
  if (req.body.foo === 'first') {
    req.alias = 'firstCall'
  } else if (req.body.foo === 'second') {
    req.alias = 'secondCall'
  }
});

// Action to trigger first call here

cy.wait('@firstCall').should((interception) => {
  // validation here
});

// Action to trigger second call here

cy.wait('@secondCall').should((interception) => {
  // validation here
});
```

[Alternatively, you can get *all* requests that are intercepted by appending `.all` onto the alias.](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/1573), or a specific intercept by appending a 1-indexed number (`.2` for the second, for example). Note: there is some discussion on how public and available `.all` and `.[x]` are and if Cypress continues to support these going forward, so be aware if implementing these.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '/url').as('call');

// Action to trigger first call here
cy.wait('@call').get('@call.1').should((interception) => {
  // validation here
});

// Action to trigger second call here

cy.wait('@call').get('@call.2').should((interception) => {
  // validation here
});

// or getting .all
cy.get('@call.all').should((interceptions) => {
  const first = interceptions[0];
  // validations on the first call here
  const second = interceptions[1];
  // validations on the second call here

});
```

Comment: I have already tried these two variants, has not worked for me :( It still gets the body from the first request.

Comment: If using the first variant gives you the incorrect requests, then I would recommend you look at your logic to determine which alias is set. If using the second variant gives you the incorrect requests, It may be worthwhile to check that the correct amount of calls has been made -> `cy.get('@call.all').should('have.length', 2).and((interceptions => { ... });`